# USDT Staking on Binance - the offer too good to be true? What could go wrong?

Tags: cryptocurrency, crypto-exchanges

Binance is currently offering around 24-26% interest when staking USDT with daily payout.

The offer looks extremely good to me, but I wonder if I am not seeing or underestimating the corresponding risk.

Was thinking of investing 10K $. How do you rate the risk of staking, especially on Binance?

USDT should remain pegged to the USD in the medium term, with the emphasis on should (remember Terra Luna...). And the fact that Binance is still not completely at peace with the US authorities is currently the biggest risk from my point of view. In other words, in the worst case scenario, you have to expect that access to your account will suddenly be blocked.

I already have experience with Coinbase and Etherum Stalking and am extremely satisfied. However, I have not invested much money there (significantly less than 10K $), I only have a larger sum due to huge price gains over time.

Comment: It doesn't deserve to be called investing, and you could lose everything. Some food for thought: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2022/11/11/tether-required-recapitalization-again/

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask if the interest rate quoted is meant to be daily, weekly, monthly or yearly (given said daily payouts), however, it's definitely something to be very careful with, given that said level of interest is extremely high even if it is yearly.

If there isn't something strange going on here, like a ponzi scheme, it's almost certainly incredibly risky. Those levels of return aren't really something you can manage in any reliable fashion, at least not unless you're a quant hedge fund employing genius mathematicians.